# [Symfony]--sfGuardPlugin--SignIn

Tags: authentication, symfony1, sfguard

I use symfony 1.4

In my index page, I have created some fields as login form.

When using sfGuardPlugin, it generate automaticly its form.

So, what I'm searching for is how to replace the default form created by the new which I have created.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `sfGuardAuth` module comes with 2 very simple templates:

- `signinSuccess.php`
- `secureSuccess.php`

If you want to customize one of these templates:

- Create a `sfGuardAuth` module in your application (don't use the
  `init-module` task, just create a `sfGuardAuth` directory)
- Create a template with the name of the template you want to customize in
  the `sfGuardAuth/templates` directory
- symfony now renders your template instead of the default one

More info: https://github.com/Garfield-fr/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Edit:

You must set up the settings.yml

```
   enabled_modules: [default, sfGuardAuth, sfGuardUser]
  .actions:
    login_module: sfGuardAuth
    login_action: signin
```

This is my signinSuccess.php

```
<h2>Bejelentkezés</h2>
<form id="loginform" action="<?php echo url_for('@sf_guard_signin') ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="signin[_csrf_token]" value="2a831d070cdd61d81bb1572be3f52d21" id="signin__csrf_token" />                 <p>
        <label class="required" for="username">Felhasználónév vagy Email:</label><br/>

        <input type="text" name="signin[username]" id="signin_username" class="text" />                 </p>

    <p>
        <label class="required" for="password">Jelszó:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="signin[password]" id="signin_password" class="text" />                 </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green big" value="Signin" />&nbsp; 

    </p>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: I followed documentation which you have sent as answer, but i couldn't understand how to implement what is done. can you explain more plz

Comment: See my settings.yml and signinSuccess.php.